# is there a way to check if a given field exists in pyspark and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a collection of documents with N fields, one of them is a string field that contain some text. This field is not in every document.

For the given task, I have 2 main choices:

1) create the field in documents where is missing and replace with some placeholder text.

2) delete the document.

In mongodb I could handle this situation easily with `{ field: { $exists: <boolean> } }` syntax but I'm using pyspark with mongodb connector. Reading the documentation I didn't find anything useful.

Anyone can suggest me a possible solution? Thanks

### Edit

As suggested in the answer, what I miss is that `pyspark.sql` module is (obviously) based on relational model and so missing document fields are treated as null (see image and reviewText fields):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming i understand you question correctly:

1. `your_df.withColumn("your_column",when(col("your_column").isNull, lit("smth")).otherwise(col("your_column"))`
2. just filter the record -> `your_df.where(col("your_column").isNotNull)`.

If it is not what u were looking for, please provide some more information about your question.(and examples).